# Restrict neuralnet output to positive values

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I am using R's neuralnet function to train 160 separate neuralnetwork models, each with two input variables, and deploy them on test data.

I need the predictions to be restricted to positive values.
I thought that specifying act.fct = "logistic" in the nueralnet function would achieve this aim.

However, it doesn't seem like the activation function is being applied.  After examining the weights, the output of the function seems to be just the sum-product of the input values and the weights plus the bias node value.

For my output, of the 9 records I am trying to predict, 2 are negative - both at -0.0885.  For simplicity, I specify a neural network with no hidden layer.  After model creation, I identified the culprit of the negative value to be the bias node.  While the weights for the two variables are positive, the bias node is negative.

```
if (require(neuralnet==F)) install.packages("neuralnet"); require(neuralnet)

for (i in 1:160) {
    training.list[[i]] <- neuralnet(nn.training[,i] ~  nn.training[,i+160]+nn.training[,i+320], nn.training, 
                              act.fct = "logistic", hidden = 0, threshold = 0.01)                                  
 }

 plot(training.list[[1]])

# Load test data in proper format 
load("nn_test.Rdata")

 # predict on only the first dataset for illustration's sake
 a <- compute(training.list[[1]], cbind(test[,1], test[,1+160]))
```

The output of a is

```
$net.result
         [,1]
  [1,]  0.44661508
  [2,]  0.31966633
  [3,]  0.01916739
  [4,] -0.08849801
  [5,] -0.08849801
  [6,]  0.39840670
  [7,]  0.33252190
  [8,]  0.33573579
  [9,]  0.38555113
```

The weights from the plot are 0.71174, 0.39118 for each input node, and -0.0891 for the bias node.

What do I need to specify in order to restrict the output to positive values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `act.fct` is **only** applied to hidden layer. If you want it to also affect output one - you have to set `linear.output = FALSE`.

From [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/neuralnet.pdf)

> `act.fct` a differentiable function that is used for smoothing the result of the cross product
>   of the covariate or neurons and the weights. Additionally the strings, ’logistic’
>   and ’tanh’ are possible for the logistic function and tangent hyperbolicus.
>
> `linear.output logical`. **If act.fct should not be applied to the output    neurons set linear output to
>   TRUE, otherwise to FALSE.**

Comment: Thanks very much lejlot.  As an aside, I would have expected my error to go down when I added hidden nodes, but it actually tanked.  Any idea why?